# Xcode 4.6.2 IOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Τhe last few days I experienced a problem with Xcode 4.6.2 when I try to run twice  an application, in IOS Simulator  only,  the program throws an exception.
Somehow the simulator keeps the instance active even though the stop button was pressed  and requires to press it again many times  in order to run it again,on the other hand in my device Xcode works properly.
Any ideas ?

Comment: I solved this problem by changing my development environment. Since the time I started using "nano" and "make", all the Xcode-related crashes are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode 4.6.3 was just released to fix a hang/crash issue with the ios simulator (and lldb debugger), particularly on osx 10.8.4.